# How to access variables from other methods inside the same class in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

I tried this but couldn't get it to work:

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {
      $foo = 'bar';
   }

   public function form_submit() {
      echo $this->index()->foo;
   }

}
```

I know I can make a variable accessible to all the methods in a class by declaring it outside all the methods at class level and declaring it as public. But here I need to declare the variable inside one of the methods.

Comment: You can't do it like that, because `$foo` is out of scope; you need to use a class property or a session variable, or do `echo $this->index();` and return `$foo`. You can, of course, make the class property `private`ly scoped, so only the class can access it.

Comment: Added the CI tag because controller methods in CodeIgniter work slightly differently from regular PHP class methods, which may or may not affect your question. But what @Jared Farrish said also works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are declaring it inside the method, you are out of luck unless you return the value.

```
class Profile {

    public function index() {
      $foo = 'bar';
      return $foo;
    }

    public function form_submit() {
      echo $this->index();
    }
}
```

A perhaps better alternative would be to declare it as an object variable (what you describe as "at class level") but declare it private.

```
class Profile {

   private $foo;

   public function index() {
      $this->foo = 'bar';
   }

   public function form_submit() {
      echo $this->foo;
   }

}
```

Comment: How about your first example if there is two variables in the `index()` method?!

Comment: @Shafizadeh you can only return one variable only, if you have to return multiple variables, then you need return an array/object

Answer (score 0):

**No! In no case, one can image that accessing a variable in another method is useful or necessary.**

A class is a collection of methods which operate on a shared state. The shared state gets created by instantiating an object of a class.

Since `index()` and `form_submit()` share the `$foo` state, your code should read like this:

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

   private
     $foo;

   public function index() {
      $this->foo = 'bar';
   }

   public function form_submit() {
      echo $this->foo;
   }

}
```

In certain situations, the [registry pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) might be helpful. But not in your case.

Alternatively, you could lift `$foo` into the global scope. But since this is **very bad style**, I'm not willing to provide a code example. Sorry.